# Xsane hangs when starting "Scanning for devices"

Tags: scanner, canon, xsane

I want to use my Canon LIDE 50 scanner. I tested with GIMP, and Xsane took a very long time to start, but did then open and scanned beautifully.

The next morning I tried to load it and it would not get past the *scanning for devices* screen.  Yesterday I had it open for the entire day, but it never got past that stage.

I have used the command prompt to verify that my scanner is correctly recognised.

Comment: When I finished with the machine for the day (It is a LinuxCNC Milling machine) I decided to close LinuxCNC instead of shutting down, I then clicked several times on the blank Xsane window (I doubt that did anything except to act as a delay for me!) and Xsane launched - I am scanning as much as I can now in case it is a fluke!  I am now wondering whether LinuxCNC holding the parallel ports could be an isue for Xsane and I just need to start Xsane first, then CNC?  Will check tomorrow, as I am not prepared to shut down till I have at least scanned a critical load!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was EMC; if I first start Xsane's dialogue, then EMC, it works fine.

Comment: LinuxCNC was formerly named EMC.